# Run same command on all terminals in mac

Tags: macos

Is there a way to run the same command on all the open terminal tabs . I usually log into many servers and want to perform the same command on all of them. Xshell (available on windows only) had this feature where you can run same command on all open terminals , i am wondering if its possible in mac somehow ?

Comment: This seems more like a systems admin question than a question about programming...

Answer (score 5):

It is most definitely possible. I do it quite often. This solves it:

```
onall () {
    if [[ $1 == "--help" ]]; then
        echo "Usage: onall <command>"
        return 0
    fi
    osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\"
        repeat with w in windows
            repeat with t in tabs of w
                do script \"${1//\"/\\\"}\" in t
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell"
}
```

`osascript` is the command-line program to run AppleScript code and the -e option tells it to use the following string as the script. The `${1//\"/\\\"}` escapes all of the quotes in the command.

You can either declare it as is in your .bash_profile or whatever other file you use or you can take it out of the function, put it into a script, make the script executable and put it somewhere that is always in your PATH.

NOTE 1: The entire command must be in the first argument.

NOTE 2: If you're doing a command with quotes in it, you must escape the quotes.

For example, `onall echo "*"` will not give the expected results. Instead, use `onall "echo \"*\""`

Answer (score 5):

iTerm2 can solve this problem.
steps:

1. split terminal as per your requirement
2. click on shell -> broadcast input (select broadcast setting as per you requirement)

Screen shot for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Terminal for this, use SSH. If it's a command you need to run in a terminal, odds are you're sshing somewhere anyway - eliminate the middle man.

Generate passwordless ssh keypair, put the public key on the remote systems, then from a single shell script you can do something like

```
for host in host1 host2 host3 ..; do
    ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_private_key username@${host} "echo HAXXXXXXXXXXXX | wall"
done
```

This is a very crude mechanism, but it's lightyears beyond having to physically open a terminal for each command.

I actually know of something that'll do what you want on OSX, but honestly it's such a generically bad idea it would be negligent of me to provide a hyperlink to it.